# What is the formula for additional experience on items?

Tags: diablo-iii

For +experience on items, it seems that the full amount of experience isn't rewarded per kill; instead, it seems based on the monster killed. On the character sheet, bonus experience is listed as "up to" the combined amount of +experience from gear.

[image: Cropped screenshot: "Every monster killed grants up to 38.00 additional experience."]

What determines how much bonus experience is granted per monster?

Answer (score 4):

The monster level versus your level determines how much xp you get, and whether or not you get any bonus xp.

If we consult [this handy chart](http://diablo3blog.blogspot.com/2012/05/diablo-3-experience-points-explained.html) you will notice at monster levels more than 5 levels below you, you get no +xp/kill bonuses.

I don't know if you would only get 23 bonus xp for killing a monster 4 levels below you though.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some quick and dirty tests, and I'm pretty sure that the bonus XP is added onto the monster's base XP *before* any multiplayer or level based calculations are applied.

This means that, for instance, you can't stack +500 XP on a nightmare-level character then one-shot a few thousand normal-mode monsters for easy XP.