# Extra experience from equipment

Tags: diablo-iii

I would like to know what happens if I wear 2 or more items that reward extra experience per kill. For example, a helmet that adds 5% extra experience and a ring that adds 8% extra experience.

What is the final extra experience I gain? 5%? 8%? 13%?

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69075/what-is-the-formula-for-additional-experience-on-items

Comment: @fbueckert I don't think its a duplicate as this asking about the xp modifications % increased. The question you link is about XP bonus +Experience per kills. They are completely different and none of the answers in that question answer this question. Although if the original poster means per kill then yes it would be a duplicate.

Comment: I didn't realize there was +exp%, outside of putting a ruby in a helmet.  If there is, though, I would assume they just add:  5% + 8% = 113%.  Although it's possible (but less likely, I would guess) they also stack:  105% * 108% = 113.4%.  If you have two such items, try putting them both on and check your +exp percentage in the "Details" tab

Comment: You cannot roll XP % bonuses on any random attributes on items.  That stat only comes from a ruby in a helm socket.

Answer (score 3):

An update on the +% experience post 1.0.4: **Leoric's Signet** will give a hefty amount of +% experience([`20-30%`](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/leorics-signet)). However, the prices for this low-level equipment may not make it worth the investment.

The 3 items of **Cain's Fate** set will give you +30% exp along with 10% Better Chance of Finding Magical Items.

Comment: According to the game guide, Leoric's Signet gives 20-30% XP bonus, so I approved the edit.

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby that you put into a helm socket is the only experience gain by percentage that is available as far as I'm aware. The +XP bonus on other items is a value that is added to each individual kill, so for example:

You kill an enemy worth 100 experience points
You have +20 experience per kill on gear

You gain 120 experience points for that kill.

In relation to the percentage gain, I am unsure if this is added before +XP per kill or after. This is something that would need testing.

Comment: There are other percentage experience increase items available (Leorics signet, Cain's set) besides a ruby socketed in a helm.

Answer (score 2):

Its additive.  You can see this listed under your character sheet (when you click on the detailed button).  A helmet with a 5% ruby and a ring with 8% bonus experience will result in 13% extra experience.  Note that any % experience items you put on your follower gets transferred over at a 20% rate (this is the same for both gold find and magic find as well).  So if you equip a 8% experience boost ring on your follower you'll gain 1.6% boosted experience.

Answer (score 2):

1. Hellfire ring of any sort=35% bonus XP
2. Full Cain's fate set (recomended socketed helm)
3. Until level 23 Socketed helm with ruby of any sort For most Xp radiant star
4. And Leoric's signet
5. In edition to that Give your follower Another Leoric's signet and Hellfire ring= an extra 11-14 XP

   ```
                  Lowest Xp you can get 90% with follower 101%

                 Highest Xp you can get 131% with follower 145%
   ```