# How much +xp is worth keeping

Tags: diablo-iii

I have read the following questions

[What Is The Formula For Additional Experience On Items](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69075/what-is-the-formula-for-additional-experience-on-items)

[What Determines How Much Experience You Get From A Kill](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69938/what-determines-how-much-experience-you-get-from-a-kill)

I understand that you get a bonus/penalty depending on the level of monster you are fighting.

My question is if my character has +52xp/kill, what percentage increase is that over act 1 and act 2 normal monsters?

I was playing tonight and I leveled up to 17 after finding the cultist hideouts.  The issue is, does it still make sense to keep the +xp gear on or not.  If the average monster gives 500 xp/kill then I can say well +52 is 10% more (or less) experience I have to obtain.  But if the monsters give 1000 xp/kill then my gear is only giving 5% and maybe I should switch out the gear.

Comment: My opinion is to forget about +xp and just use a helm with a socket and the best ruby you can find/buy. It gives a flat % extra xp, so it's always relevant, and when you find a helmet that's an upgrade (as long as it's got a socket), you can just move the ruby to it and keep your bonus experience.

Comment: yes, but socket items do not come until act 3 or 4... other than that I agree.

Comment: I'd say normal passes by so quickly that it's not really worth it to spend too much time pondering on how to optmize gear. You will usually find a new piece of gear within an hour or two anyways.

Comment: It almost depends on how you play.  Do you prefer to go ahead of where you should be on your leveling, or going behind?  It is always style of play.  And don't forget, as I mentioned in my answer, the best EXP item in the game is the best weapon you can use at the time :)

Comment: you should be able to see how much experience you need to level by hovering over your xp bar.  After that, you can figure out if its worth keeping your + xp gear.  for instance, if it takes 50k xp to level and you have +50 total xp, then it means for 1000 kills you'll gain 1 additional level.  Its a rough way to estimate if its worth it to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sockets are available at level 15, at that time I always end up getting a helm and socketing it for + % experience.

What I always ended up doing when leveling, like my level 40 Hardcore Monk, is every 5-10 levels I will check the auction house to see if there is better EXP gear available.  I would always try to find EXP rings and amulets that still had at least one good stat other than EXP.  The best form of EXP is having the best weapon available (what's the point of having a +10 EXP with a 15 [DPS](http://www.diablowiki.net/Damage_Per_Second) weapon when you can have a 45 DPS weapon and kill things 300% faster).  If you check every 5 to 10 levels you should notice a good jump in the + EXP for each item and they should be relatively cheap.

Part of it also matters on how you level.  Are you way ahead of the game for your level and fighting creatures that are +5 your level, and what you kill gives more experience and takes you a little longer to kill each mob, or are you a little behind for your level (as I am since I am Hardcore) where the + EXP means more both because I kill things faster and they give me less experience.  Obviously, the + EXP equipment is worth keeping if you are a little behind.

In short: With my level 40 Hardcore Monk: I am still holding on to some of my EXP gear, but I always find the best one-handed weapon and shield. My + exp rings, amulet and other gear typically have one good important stat that helps (Vitality or Dexterity or Resistance).  Every little chunk helps, if you kill a monster that is a little below your level and only receive 50 exp for it, the +52 exp as you mentioned makes a MAJOR difference (over 100% more experience).  Even if you got 300 EXP per kill that will make it 352 EXP (17% increase) which in *theory* means you will level 17% faster.  :)

Comment: I guess that is why I am asking the question.  The largest gem I have is flawless square +19% so if my +xp is greater than 19% I think the +xp would be better?

Comment: That is correct.  I've always held onto both for those reasons.  It all falls back to your playing style.  If you chose to play ahead of your level, you would want the 19% Flawless Square.  If you chose to play a little behind your level, you are *PROBABLY* better off going with the +EXP.

Answer (score 2):

As with Magic Find and Gold Find, the answer is "as much as you can wear without harming your ability to effectively clear content."

More +XP(/GF/MF) is never a bad thing. The returns are linear and there are no 'caps' that make some magic amount of it better than more or less. You either want +XP, or you don't. If you do, It will always benefit you more than overkill stats. But the instant you start having difficulty, it becomes a liability. Where you draw that line is up to you.